# newer version of "Documentation for Android SDK" for offline usages

Tags: android

I use `Android Studio 3.2.1`. While online `Android SDK docs` contains documents up to `API level 28`, my offline SDK docs only contains up to `API level 24`.

I tried `sdkmanager` to update offline docs, but command line `sdkmanager` and also `SDK Manager` of `Android Studio` do not show available update for `Documentation for Android SDK`.

Also I uninstalled existing documentations by `SDK Manager` and reinstall it, but it is same as older.

How I can get newer version of `SDK documentation`?